# Firebase realtime DB rule based on data.child do not work

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I like to retrieve the list of items only the ones its delete flag is false. but this setting does not work.

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      ".read": "data.child('isDelete').val() == false",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth != null && !data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a result from Rules playground request I tried.

Request details

```js
{
  "auth": null,
  "resource": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "path": "/items",
  "method": "get",
  "time": "2022-07-07T09:24:31.042Z"
}
```

Result details

```js
Line 4 (/items)
read: "data.child('isDelete').val() == false"
```

The data structure

```js
items
- 1xxxxxxxxxx
 title:"title text 1"
 createdAt:"2022-06-05T04:21:57.322Z"
 isDelete:false
- 2xxxxxxxxxxxxx
 title:"title text 2"
 createdAt:"2022-06-05T04:21:50.322Z"
 isDelete:true
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the exact query you're perfoming?

Comment: Hey @cieux1  Any update here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be missing that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) on their own. All the rules do is check for any incoming operation whether it is allowed, and in your try from the playground you are trying to read all of `/items`, rather than just the items with `isDelete` set to false, to that isn't allowed.

There is no way to perform the necessary query from the playground, but in code you can get the items with this query:

```
ref.orderByChild("isDelete").equalTo(false)
```

Now the operation matches the condition in your rules, and is only trying to read data that it is allowed to, so the rules will allow the operation.

---

**Update**: I forgot that [query-based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) in the Realtime Database actually require that you write the rule as this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      ".read": "query.orderByChild === 'isDelete' && query.equalTo === false",
      ...
```

**Now** the query only tries to retrieve non-deleted data, and the security rules correctly validate this.

Comment: I tried this query 
`const _items = query(ref(db, 'items'), orderByChild("isDelete").equalTo(false), limitToLast(10))`

then I got this error.
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...)(...).equalTo is not a function`

Comment: why `equalTo` does not work here?

Comment: Oops, I has missed that you need to also update the rules. I added an update to my answer to show what you need there, but be sure to also read the documentation I linked as it explains more abut query-based security rules.

Comment: Yea, it worked. I had to fix the query to `query(ref(db, 'items/'), orderByChild("isDelete"), equalTo(false))`. It seems like `orderByChild` and `equalTo` can not be chained with `.` in the `query()` like in your answer tho. Arigato!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working cieux1!  The syntax in my answer is the namespaced API of the v8 and earlier JavaScript SDKs, and it sounds like you're using the modular API of v9 and later. This is one of the many reasons Alex asked for the actual code you run in a comment to your question, so that we can use that in our answers, so that might be something to keep in mind going forward.